# AppGyver rootview can't open URL

Tags: angularjs, html, coffeescript, steroids

According to their [tutorial](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/guides/architecture/app-config-files/#app-coffee):

> All location properties can be either a Supersonic routes or URLs.

When I use this in structure.coffee, nothing is loaded, only the initial splash screen is shown:

```
 rootView:
     location: "http://example.com/page1"
```

What else should I set?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a current issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/821).

From that post:

```
A workaround is to run a local clone of Steroids and change
https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/blob/master/src/steroids/features.coffee#L6 
to be false, after which you can write

splashscreen:
    autohide: true
```

in your `config/app.coffee`.